# Spark 2.0.1 not finding file passed in through archives flag

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, pyspark, hdfs, hadoop-yarn

I was running `Spark` job which make use of other files that is passed in through `--archives` flag of spark

`spark-submit .... --archives hdfs:///user/{USER}/{some_folder}.zip .... {file_to_run}.py`

Spark is currently running on YARN and when I tried it with spark version 1.5.1 it was fine.

However, when I ran the same commands with `spark 2.0.1`, I got

`ERROR yarn.ApplicationMaster: User class threw exception: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/home/{USER}/{some_folder}/.....": error=2, No such file or directory`

Since the resource is managed by `YARN`, it is challenging to manually check if the file gets successfully decompressed and exist when the job runs.

I wonder if anyone has experienced similar issue.

Comment: Your `{USER}` and `{some_folder}` is not translated to actual user and folder name. And hadoop cannot find the path

Comment: they are just place holders for this post since I do not want to reveal my information, everything was being translated correctly

Comment: the path to the zip folder is wrong. Thats what the error message is saying `No such file or directory`. If you have set HADOOP_HOME, then you can remove `hdfs://`